# Kill or continue lost Linux sessions

Tags: linux, session, kill-process

I have an unreliable Internet connection. Sometimes it is lost while logged on to the text command interface of a Ubuntu server. This results in a "garbage" user session (seen when using the `who` command).

Is there any way I can login to the server and continue an old session, or should I kill the "garbage" sessions? In that case, how do I do that without killing the current session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) and [tmux](http://tmux.sourceforge.net/) are your friend here. Run your remote commands in a screen session and when you lose connection and reconnect, you can simply reattach to those sessions.

Comment: Sounds like great programs. I'll give them a shot. No way to reconnect using a standard Linux textual command?

Comment: Those *are* the standard :)